# Phonegap App Store Submit: ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - NFCReaderUsageDescription - Not Using Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using Application Loader on my mac to upload an ipa built by Adobe Phonegap Build. I get an email shortly after from the app store:

`ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NFCReaderUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).`

I've scoured the web for answers and tried many solutions like different ways of adding the key/string to info.plist, but nothing has worked. The only thing I can think of is Phonegap Build is overwriting something. The crazy thing is, I'm not evening using the cordova NFC reader plugin! I looked in my project.pbxproj file and there are not references to anything NFC. I'm very frustrated and confused.

Here's my global config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="net.buildix.app" version="2.0.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Buildix</name>
    <description>
        Building automation suite.
    </description>
    <author email="support@buildix.net" href="https://buildix.net">Cloudulus.Media</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Buildix/2.0 Android" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Buildix/2.0 iOS" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <config-file parent="NFCReaderUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>Reading NFC tags is used as an additional layer of multi-factor authentication.</string>
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <platform name="winphone">
        <preference name="windows-identity-name" value="59705Cloudulus.Media.Buildix" />
        <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.2" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.4" />
    <engine name="windows" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.4" />
</widget>
```

This version of my config file reflects my latest (failed) attempt to try to get the app store to see my description string, but nothing has worked. I even tried directly editing Buildix-Info.plist to add it manually... nothing!

Can someone please shed any light on this, give me any other options to try. I figure I can a.) get the app store to "see" my description string, or b.) remove any reference to NFC reader, which I have no use for.

Any help would be appreciated. I don't think I'm going to use phonegap any more after this...

Answer (score 0):

Your description string must contain a well described text to clearly indicate the purpose of using NFC to the end user. A user should clearly understand for what functionality he is giving you the permission.

Your current text is not detailed from a user point of view

Comment: That may be so, and I will come up with a more detailed explanation, but I'm thinking that my submission is being screened by AI because it gets rejected rather quickly. Do you think that their AI is smart enough to understand my purpose string?

Comment: Also, the email says that I'm "missing purpose string" not that the purpose string I supplied is inadequate...

Comment: Did you try adding NFCReaderUsageDescription directly from project's info.plist?

Comment: and removing it from config.xml?